# Need a good Solana RPC

Tags: rpc

Where can I get Solana free RPC/public RPC? I tried looking on google but got different answers with varying results - Tien

Comment: Helius and Triton are the two main "Solana" ones in that they are Solana-native. Each provider has pros and cons (so be careful if a provider says things like "we are the fastest"). Source: I'm the CEO of Helius — happy to chat in DMs anytime!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the unique expertise required to run Solana nodes, there are very few Solana providers in the space.

Check out QuickNode: https://www.quicknode.com/

- There's a free lifetime plan.
- It's the fastest RPC provider.

It gives you the lowest latency regardless of your location.

Check out this blog post: https://blog.quicknode.com/quicknode-the-quickest-solana-node-provider/

Answer (score 9):

Helius offers a free tier that's very easy to use. All you need is a Solana wallet to get started.

https://dev.helius.xyz/dashboard/app

https://www.helius.dev/